# How to select certain geometries from a geometrycollection after st_intersect?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I am running an intersect of two polygons or other sf objects using the fantastic new sf package. It's similar to this:

```
a <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,0,7.5,7.5,0),c(0,-1,-1,0,0))))
b <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,0),c(1,0,.5,0,0,0.5,-0.5,-0.5,1,1))))
i <- st_intersection(a,b)
## GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1 0), LINESTRING(4 0, 3 0), POLYGON((5.5 0, 7 0, 7 -0.5, 6 -0.5, 5.5 0)))
```

how do I only keep the `POLYGON` of the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`? Selecting different types in a feature collection is easy enough, but I can't seem to find the equivalent of ST_CollectionExtract in the sf package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Output is a list so that you can extract with `i[[3]]` here.
If you a more standard way to find which element is a polygon use:

```
w.pol <- purrr::map_lgl(i, ~st_is(.x, c("POLYGON", "MULTIPOLYGON")))
pol <- i[[which(w.pol)]]

##> pol
## POLYGON((5.5 0, 7 0, 7 -0.5, 6 -0.5, 5.5 0))
```

Edit: If you have a `sfc`, you can use `st_cast` to separate feature types, and then select the lines of interest:

```
# Simple feature data frame of spatial collection
a1 <- st_sf(a=1, geom = st_sfc(i))
a2 <- st_sf(a=2, geom = st_sfc(i))

ii <- rbind(a1, a2)

# Use st_cast to separate all features types
st_cast(ii)[which(st_is(st_cast(ii), c("POLYGON", "MULTIPOLYGON"))),]
```

### Edit: 2017-12-23

You can directly use:

```
st_collection_extract(i, "POLYGON")
```

Comment: Thx, this works well in this case! @StatnMap, how would you do that when the geometrycollection is part of a simple features data frame and not just a single object? This will just remove all collections then, but they may have polygons inside.

Comment: What if the simple features data frame contains not only `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`s but also other geometries, e.g. if I change `a2 <- st_sf(a=2, geom = st_sfc(i))` to `a2 <- st_sf(a=2, geom = st_sfc(a))` in the above?