# Retain only two-dimensional components in sf data.frame

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have a similar setup as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723775/how-to-select-certain-geometries-from-a-geometrycollection-after-st-intersect). In my case, however, I've got an `sf` data.frame that contains a mix of different geometry types, some `POLYGON`s, some `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`s like so:

```
a <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,0,7.5,7.5,0),c(0,-1,-1,0,0))))
b <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,0),c(1,0,.5,0,0,0.5,-0.5,-0.5,1,1))))
i <- st_intersection(a,b)

a1 <- st_sf(a=1, geom = st_sfc(i))
a2 <- st_sf(a=2, geom = st_sfc(a))

ii <- rbind(a1, a2)
```

As in the question referenced above, what I would like is to retain only those parts of the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` that are two-dimensional as ultimately I'm interested in the areas of these geometries and `st_area()` won't work on `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`s.

In the case of mixed geometries, however, the answer given

```
st_cast(ii)[which(st_is(st_cast(ii), c("POLYGON", "MULTIPOLYGON"))),]
```

doesn't work as the `st_cast()` leaves the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
st_collection_extract(ii)
```

? And what did you mean by `st_area` not working on collections? I see

```
 > st_area(ii)
[1] 0.625 7.500
```

Comment: Is `st_collection_extract()` new in 0.5.5? If so that may have been my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution but it works:

```
split(ii, 1:nrow(ii)) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ st_cast(.x) %>% 
                 filter(st_dimension(.) == 2)) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .)
```