# st_intersection to spatialpolygon dataframe not working

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, tigris

I am trying to get the intersection of two shapefiles (census tracts that fall within the boundaries of certain metropolitan areas). I am able to successfully get the intersecting features, however when I try to convert the output of sf_intersect to a SpatialPolygonsDataframe I get the error:

> "Error in as_Spatial(from) :    conversion from feature type
>   sfc_GEOMETRY to sp is not supported"

This is my code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tigris)
library(sp)

#download shapefiles corresponding to metro areas 
metro_shapefiles<-core_based_statistical_areas(cb = FALSE, year = 2016)
#convert to sf and filter
metro_shapefiles<-st_as_sf(metro_shapefiles)%>%filter(GEOID==31080 )
#Data for California
census_tracts_california<-tracts(state="CA",year=2016)
census_tracts_california<-st_as_sf(census_tracts_california)

#INTERSECT AND CONVERT BACK TO SP
census_tracts_intersected1<-st_intersection(census_tracts_california,
                                            metro_shapefiles)

#back to spatial
census_tracts_intersected1<-as(census_tracts_intersected1,"Spatial")
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. You can't convert an `sfc` object to `sp`. Use `st_join` instead, it returns an `sf` object, not `sfc`

Comment: Also, why do you want an `sp` object? `sf` has superseeded `sp`.

Comment: If the answer was clear enough I wouldn't be here wouldn't I? also the reason why I perform an intersection (as the name indicates) is because I am interested in getting the polygons that fall within the boundaries of the other object; with union you get all the features regardless of if they intersect or not.

Comment: `class(census_tracts_intersected1)` returns `"sf"   "data.frame"` so it seems that the result of `st_intersection` is a `sf` object not `sfc`. That makes the error message and the previous comments nit so clear indeed... By the way, transforming back to `sp` is still necessary for interactions with packages that do not support `sf`

Comment: @Gilles - yes you're right - I meant with reference to the geometry column - I wasn't clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select certain geometries from a geometrycollection after st\_intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723775/how-to-select-certain-geometries-from-a-geometrycollection-after-st-intersect)

Answer (score 6):

The error message is telling you you can't convert an `sfc_GEOMETRY` to a `Spatial` object. There is no `sp` equivalent object.

In your intersection result you have a mixture of geometries (and hence, you're returned an `sfc_GEOMETRY` as your 'geometry'). You can see all the geometries here:

```
types <- vapply(sf::st_geometry(census_tracts_intersected1), function(x) {
    class(x)[2]
}, "")

unique(types)
# [1] "POLYGON"         "MULTILINESTRING" "MULTIPOLYGON"
```

If you want, you can extract each type of geometry, and convert those to SP individually:

```
lines <- census_tracts_intersected1[ grepl("*LINE", types), ]
polys <- census_tracts_intersected1[ grepl("*POLYGON", types), ]

spLines <- as(lines, "Spatial")
spPolys <- as(polys, "Spatial")
```

---

### Additional Information

I mentioned in the comments you could use `st_join`. However, this may not give you the result you want. Within `sf` library there are the geometric binary predicates, such as `?st_intersects`, and geometric operations such as `?st_intersection`

The predicates return a sparse (default) or dense matrix telling you with which geometry of y each geometry of x intersects. If you use this within `st_join`, it will return the (original) geometries that intersect, rather than the sparse matrix.

Whereas the operations (e.g. `st_intersection`) will compute the intersection, and return new geometries.

#### Example use

The predicates (`st_intersects`) can be used inside [`st_join`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_join.html), and they will return the original geometries which 'intersect'

```
sf_join <- sf::st_join(census_tracts_california, metro_shapefiles, join = st_intersects)
```

In this case this gives a single `type` of object

```
types <- vapply(sf::st_geometry(sf_join), function(x) {
  class(x)[2]
}, "")

unique(types)
# [1] "MULTIPOLYGON"

## so you can convert to a Spatial object
spPoly <- as(sf_join, "Spatial")
```

But you need to decide if the result of `st_intersect` is what you're after, or whether you need the new geometries given by `st_intersection`.

#### Further reading

- information on each join is on the [sf blog](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html).
- spatial predicates and examples of what the different operations do are on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) (with some good illustrations)

---

Credit to user @lbussett for their description on the difference between `st_intersect` and `st_intersection`

Comment: Very useful reply thanks ! Is it possible to force an intersection to return only polygons or multipolygons to make the result directly compatible with sp ? If I understand well you suggested in a previous comment that this should be possible with `st_join`. I tried `res <- st_join(census_tracts_california, metro_shapefiles, join = st_intersection)` that returns an error but I'm not certain to understand how this function works.

Comment: @Gilles I'm not sure that it would make sense to convert a `LINESTRING` to a `POLYGON` because they are different, and it would make the result incorrect. Also, see my edit. I've tried to add additional information, hopefully it makes sense

Comment: I was more thinking about a way to ask the function o drop the lines (as you do "manually" in your answer), not transforming them into polygons. As you mension `st_intersection` does not change the geometries so no problem with this one. Problem arise when you need to do operations on the geometries and that the result is a mix of plygons, lines etc...

Comment: @SymbolixAU AFAIK, in `sf` (as well as in POSTGIS), `st_intersects` only checks if two (or more) features intersect in 2D. It returns a sparse (default) or dense matrix telling you with which geometry of y each geometry of x intersects. `st_intersection` instead "computes" the intersection and returns new geometries.

Comment: @lbusett - that makes a lot of sense - thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion to a `Spatial` object can't handle mixed lines and polygons. After the intersection you can extract just the polygons (and discard any lines) using:
`st_collection_extract("POLYGON")`

Your example doesn't seem to fail anymore, so I've created a new example that intersects two polygons, with a shared side. This results in an intersection output of a polygon and a line.
On the second attempt I've piped the intersection through the st_collection_extract() function prior to successful conversion to a `Spatial` object.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)

#Create some boxes
BoxA <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,0,2,2,0),c(0,2,2,0,0))))
BoxB <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(1,1,3,3,1),c(1,3,3,1,1))))
BoxC <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(2,2,4,4,2),c(0,2,2,0,0))))

#Create a funny shaped union to help demonstrate the intersection issue
BoxAB <- st_union(BoxA,BoxB)

plot(BoxAB)
plot(BoxC,add=TRUE,border="blue")
```

[Example polygons to intersect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du3op.png)

```
#Intersect of BoxAB with BoxC results in a line and a polygon
BoxIntersects<-st_intersection(BoxAB,BoxC)
plot(BoxIntersects)
```

[Intersection made up of a polygon and a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hTCZ.png)

```
#back to spatial fails
SpatialVersionOfIntersects<-as(BoxIntersects,"Spatial")
```

Error in .as_Spatial(from, cast, IDs) :
conversion from feature type sfc_GEOMETRY to sp is not supported

```
#Intersect again, but this time extract only the polygons
BoxIntersects<-st_intersection(BoxAB,BoxC) %>% st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

#back to spatial succeeds!
SpatialVersionOfIntersects<-as(BoxIntersects,"Spatial")
```